# Bash Numerical Variables as sed Parameters

Tags: bash, file, parsing, variables, sed

I have many very large files. Within each file it repeats 3 times. My intent is to delete the first portion of all of them such that only the last two repeats remain.

The code I have loops through the lines and identifies the position of each repeat (via a counter) and saves them as a variable (FIRST and END). My hope is that I would then use: `sed -i '${FIRST},${END}d ${i}.log'` to cut out that section of the file.
However when I run the code I get an error as follows: `sed: -e expression #1, char 3: extra characters after command`

Here is the code that reads the files, where "Cite" is the keyword that identifies repeats:

```
while read -r LINE ; do
    ((LCOUNT++))
    if [[ "$LINE" =~ "Cite" ]] ; then
        ((CITE++))
        if [[ "$CITE" = 1 ]] ; then
            FIRST=${LCOUNT}
        fi
        if [[ "$CITE" = 2 ]] ; then
            END=$((LCOUNT - 1))
        fi
    fi
done < "./${i}.log"
```

Comment: Shouldn't those be `==` or `-eq`?

Comment: You need to work on your shell quoting. Shell variables are only substituted inside `" "`, not `' '`. Also, the sed program and the file name need to be separate arguments.

Comment: @rici Thanks that worked. In my code the file name and the sed argument are seperated, I appear to have mistyped. Thanks for the input.

Comment: can `Cite` show up more than 3 times in a single file?  if `Cite` only shows up 3 times it may speed things up a bit if you `break` out of the `while` loop once you've got `FIRST` and `END`; as currently written if you (accidentally) run the script a 2nd time you'll delete a 2nd `Cite` block so, it might make sense to set `FIRST/END` based on the 2nd and 3rd instances (ie, `"$CITE" = 2/3`)?  if you have access to a newer version of `GNU awk` (with support for `-i inplace`) your processing will likely go a lot faster (as opposed to a really slow `while` loop + `sed`)

Comment: Show the sed command that's throwing the errors.

Comment: @Jack : Of course a  `if [ $CITE -eq 1 ]` would make more sense, or even better `if ((CITE == 1))`, but in this concrete case, I think the OP's version would work too.

Answer (score 0):

Your command

```
sed -i '${FIRST},${END}d ${i}.log'
```

does not make sense. You call sed here with two arguments: The option

```
-i
```

and a single string which is **literally**

```
${FIRST},${END}d ${i}.log
```

Since you have used single quotes, no parameter expansion occurs, and the whole piece is passed to sed as a single argument to be interpreted as a sed program. sed tries to read from stdin (since you have not passed a file argument), and the sed program obviously does not make sense.

You could do something like

```
sed $FIRST,${END}d "${i}.log"
```

A note aside, regarding the title of your post: "numerical variables" do not exist in bash. Every variable is a string. You can do a

```
typeset -i foo
```

which makes bash do some processing to ensure that the strings assigned represent natural numbers, but they are still strings. For instance,

```
foo=abc  # sets foo to the string 0
foo=00005 # sets foo to the string 5
foo=5a # raises an error
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -ni '/Cite/!{p;b};:a;n;//!ba;:b;n;p;bb' file1 file2 ... filen
```

Turn off implicit printing `-n` and turn on edit inplace `-i`.

If a line does not match `Cite`, print it and repeat.

Otherwise filter following lines until another match and then print the remaining lines until the end of the file.

N.B. The `-i` treats each file separately in the same way the `-s` option does but edits the files inplace, so make sure by using the `-s` option first and when satisfied the results are as expected substitute the `-i` option.